# how to implement camera view layer for qr code scanning iphone application?

Tags: iphone, camera, scanning

I am writing iphone application where i want qr code scanning.I have QR code library to scan QR code. And now I want to give QR code scanning interface to my iPhone application.

In Android I could achieve this using `SurfaceView` that is the view where we can show camera frames. Is there anything available in iPhone equilvalent to surfaceview in Android? If so how to do this. Please give me a tutorial or example links.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)TakePicture:(id)sender {

// Create image picker controller
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

// Set source to the camera
imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // Delegate is self
    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    OverlayView *overlay = [[OverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];     

    // Insert the overlay:
    imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;

   // Allow editing of image ?
    imagePicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    [imagePicker setCameraDevice:
    UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront];
    [imagePicker setAllowsEditing:YES];
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls=YES;
    imagePicker.navigationBarHidden=YES;
    imagePicker.toolbarHidden=YES;
    imagePicker.wantsFullScreenLayout=YES;

    self.library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    // Show image picker
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

Make a UIView class and add this code

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code


        // Clear the background of the overlay:
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        // Load the image to show in the overlay:
        UIImage *overlayGraphic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"overlaygraphic.png"];
        UIImageView *overlayGraphicView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:overlayGraphic];
        overlayGraphicView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 100, 260, 200);
        [self addSubview:overlayGraphicView];

    }
    return self;
}
```

You can also refer to this link: http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=821

Comment: Thanx a lot. It would really help me. Can u tell me how to get camera frames from camera. it is needed since i need to process the camera frames for qr code scanning.

Comment: I doubt if you can get frames, AFAIK, only capture is the thing you can get.

Comment: In android we could get the camera preview frames using onPreviewFrame call. Is there any exists in android such that? Otherwise how could qrcode application scan qrcode?

Comment: Yeah, This question did struck in mind. But, My knowledge is limited on QRCodeScanning :)

Comment: Its ok thanx a lot for ur responses :)

Answer (score 0):

QR code detection is readily available in iOS since iOS 7, the trick is to tell a `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` instance to detect objects with type `AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode`.

Live camera preview (with access to pixels if you still want to use that) is in iOS for a long time, easiest with `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.

See here for an example http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-reader-swift/